# Difference between "original" and "genuine"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I often buy something in an online shop. I noticed some descriptions say an item is *original* or *genuine*. What is the difference?

For example, say there's an Apple USB cable, and another, fake Apple USB cable.
So should I say the first one is "original Apple cable" or "genuine Apple cable"? Which is better, which is more common?

Comment: Did you look up the two words in a dictionary? If so, what did you find confusing about the definitions?

Comment: @BraddSzonye When several dictionaries define one of the words by the other, but the usage and subtle connotation calls for a distinction, I don't think it is a general reference that can be resolved by simply looking it up.

Answer (score 4):

**[Genuine](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/genuine)** can mean

> not fake or counterfeit; original; real; authentic

**[Original](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/original)** can mean

> [USUALLY BEFORE NOUN] not copied from something else

In that sense, both words are often used to describe a product that is authentic and comes from the entity that created the item in the first instance. However there are different uses of both terms that one or the other more appropriate in some circumstances.

**[Original](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/original)** can also mean

> [ONLY BEFORE NOUN] existing at the beginning of a period or process, before any changes have been made

Something can be a version of a product that is not identical to the first version, but is still *authorized* by the person or entity that creates or controls the rights to the first version. You can have **genuine** team jerseys (licensed by the team) that are not identical to the **original** team jerseys worn by players.

Similarly, products evolve. I may have an iPod from 2001. I just gave my wife a new iPod, manufactured in 2013.  Mine is **original** and **genuine**.  Hers is **genuine**, but not **original**.

Comment: Maybe even not *the* original iPod? As in "hers is *genuine*, but not the *original*".

Comment: @Prof.Falken I agree. *Original*, in particular can be used as a noun, and then it can take one a whole new meaning, such as the very first one ever made/issued, or even the prototype, in mild contrast to the *original* design.

Comment: The street artist painted a genuine fake of the original Mona Lisa.

Answer (score 1):

*Original* means "first."  *Genuine* means "real" or "not fake."

So the Apple cable could be genuine but not original, if Apple really made it, but it isn't the actual cable the item first shipped with.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point out, *genuine* is a statement about who manufactured the product, while *original* is about the revision history. With computer hardware (also automobiles), which is probably what's being discussed here, there is the somewhat hybrid acronym *OEM,* which is Original Equipment Manufacturer. So if a firm advertise that they use only OEM Parts in their repairs, they are saying that the replacement parts are genuinely produced by the original manufacturer.

Whether OEM parts are worth some price premium can not, of course, be settled on ELU!